# KO binding issue

Tags: knockout.js

I am using KO for binding one object to perticular div.  Below is my code.

```
 <div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: name" />
</div>
<div id="testDiv" style="border:solid red">
    <label for="txtProductName">Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtProductName" name="txtProductName" data-bind="value: ProductName"/>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var ViewModel = function () {
                var self = this;
                self.name = ko.observable("Hemant");
                self.age = ko.observable(50);
                self.address = ko.observable("Pune");                
            };

            var vm = new ViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(vm);

            var product = {
                ProductName: ko.observable(),
                Price: ko.observable(),
                Desc: ko.observable()
            };           
           ko.applyBindings(product, $('#testDiv')[0]);
        });
    </script>
}
```

'name' field is attached properly.  But I am not able to bind'ProductName'.  Getting below error message

> Message: TypeError: 'ProductName' is undefined;

Can you please help?
Regards,
Hemant

Answer (score 1):

Your initial applyBindings is applying vm to the whole page, so calling the second applyBindings doesn't bind product to your div correctly. So knockout is trying to get ProductName off vm.

You can either bind vm to the div above, or else make Product a property of vm

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("Hemant");
    self.age = ko.observable(50);
    self.address = ko.observable("Pune");
    self.Product = {
        ProductName: ko.observable(),
        Price: ko.observable(),
        Desc: ko.observable()
        }
    };
```

Then you can use a with binding to target Product at your div:

```
<div id="testDiv" style="border:solid red" data-bind="with: Product">
    <label for="txtProductName">Product Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtProductName" name="txtProductName" data-bind="value: ProductName"/>
</div>
```

There is a third way, where you can bind specific view models to different parts of the page:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function ()
    {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinding = true;
```

Then using:

```
<!-- ko stopBinding: true -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

html comments in your web page to stop binding.